# Node.js Rerun page (and generate new data) upon page refresh

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, nodemon

I have a web page running in Node.js (I an using `ejs` to render pages using the default folder setup provided by *WebStorm*). Currently I run `node bin/www` which contains the following:

```
***preamble***
var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('tennis-geek:server');
var http = require('http');
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);
var server = http.createServer(app);
***rest of code***
```

This then runs the `app.js` file which contains the following:

```
...
var predictions =  require("./routes/predictions");
app.use("/predictions", predictions);
...
```

**This is where the issue lies**. In the javascript file for this page (`routes/predictions.js`) I want to display information collected from two remote sources (`www.source_json.com` and `www.source_csv.com`).(As there are only two sources I have decided to do the web requests synchronously). This is private information which I don't want the end user to be able to access, so I thought it would be best to process and merge these data server side and then any final data I want the user to be able to see is saved into a javascript object called `data_array` and is sent to the corresponding `ejs` page (`views/predictions.ejs`) via:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var recline = ("reclinejs");
var papa = require("papaparse");
var request = require('sync-request');

    //Now I collect the Data.

var res = request('GET', 'www.source_json.com');
var data_1_json = JSON.parse(res.getBody('utf8'));
res = request('GET', 'www.source_csv.com');
var data_2_json = papa.parse(res.getBody('utf8'), {header: true, skipEmptyLines: true}).data;

    //Now I do some private number crunching on the data

var data_array = private_number_crunching(data_1_json, data_2_json);

    //Now I send make this information available to the user's browser

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('predictions', {title: 'Predictions', data_from_js: data_array});
});
module.exports = router;
```

The data collected from the two remote sources changes about every 20 mins. However, when I refresh the page the data isn't recollected from the two data sources (I have verified this using some timestamps). ***How can I ask Node.js to return freshly sourced data each time the page is requested?*** Is there an `update button` I can create on the page, or some javascript I can add? Currently the only way I can refresh the info is to restart the server (`CTRL + C` + `node bin/www`).

So far I have tried using `setInterval` loops, `while` loops, adding `<% setTimeout('window.location.reload();', 20000); %>`. Additionally I have considered using `nodemon` to watch some pseudo file which could contain a time when the data sources last changed the information and then restart the server if it does change, but I would like to avoid this.

Additionally I have looked at "similar" topics:

- [How do I force a page to refresh the data upon reload after entering new record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427682/how-do-i-force-a-page-to-refresh-the-data-upon-reload-after-entering-new-record)
- [node.js get new data without refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21768579/node-js-get-new-data-without-refresh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this works:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var recline = ("reclinejs");
var papa = require("papaparse");
var request = require('sync-request');

//Now I collect the Data.



//Now I send make this information available to the user's browser

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    var response1 = request('GET', 'www.source_json.com');
    var data_1_json = JSON.parse(response1.getBody('utf8'));
    var response2 = request('GET', 'www.source_csv.com');
    var data_2_json = papa.parse(response2.getBody('utf8'), {header: true,     skipEmptyLines: true}).data;

   //Now I do some private number crunching on the data

   var data_array = private_number_crunching(data_1_json, data_2_json);
   res.render('predictions', {title: 'Predictions', data_from_js: data_array});
   });
   module.exports = router;
```

Comment: I have restructured the code into the above form (defining the function `private_number_crunching()` before `router.get('/', ...`) and the function works fine outside of  `router.get('/', ...` but using the above gives me the following error in the browser:
 `undefined is not a function` `TypeError: undefined is not a function` 
`at /Users/oliver/WebstormProjects/tennis-geek/routes/predictions.js:248:9` where line 248 refers to `res.render('predictions' ....);`. Any idea why it seems not to like the function within this scope? (thanks for the reply @LiterallyIlliterate)

Comment: Also, in the console it gives the message: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`.

Comment: I have changed the code, `res` in the variable must have been the issue.

Comment: Great Spot @LiterallyIlliterate. It's now working just how I wanted!